# HttpClient and IHttpClientFactory inheritance logic

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am creating a client like this in `Startup.cs` class.

```
services.AddHttpClient("myClient", client => 
{
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test.com");
});
```

Then I have a client file `Client.cs`

```
protected readonly HttpClient httpClient;
public Client(HttpClient httpClient)
{
  this.httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

Now, when I extend my Client class in `ServiceClass.cs`:

```
private readonly HttpClient _myClient;
public ServiceClass(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) : base(//What should I pass here?)
{
  _myClient = httpClientFactory.CraeteClient("myClient");
}
```

I am not sure what object should I pass here, or maybe my code structure is incorrect. Please help!

Comment: If you're inheriting `ServiceClass` from `Client`, why do you have both `httpClient` and `_myClient`?

Comment: Sorry, I am extending Client.cs class. I am trying to initialize the constructor of Client class where I should pass HttpClient. Sorry, if I am unable to explain the logic correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `_myClient` field entirely since you have a protected field `httpClient` and instead let the base constructor handle it:

```
public ServiceClass(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) : 
base(httpClientFactory.CraeteClient("myClient")) 
{}
```

Code presumes you aren't looking for two different `HttpClient` members.

Comment: Yes, I only need to construct one client. When I handle the creation of a client in the base class, I need access to that client inside ServiceClass too.

Comment: @Sara That's what `protected` does.

Comment: @SaraMannings since it's marked `protected` all inherited classes have access.  So given your response I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. You made it very clear. Thanks lot

Comment: _CraeteClient_ -> _CreateClient_ typo

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I copied that from OP's code.  I noticed it.